# Haskell is slower in parallel

Tags: performance, haskell, parallel-processing, threadscope

I've been experimenting with parallelizing Haskell programs. To my surprise most of my attempts made my examples run slower, so I decided to dig into Threadscope and started following the tutorial [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/ThreadScope_Tour).

In [part 5](https://wiki.haskell.org/ThreadScope_Tour/Profile2) the example program sudoku3 is introduced, which is suppoed to be an example of a well-parallelized Haskell program. So I compiled it like described in the tutorial with

```
ghc -O2 sudoku3.hs -threaded -rtsopts -eventlog
```

and (not like described in the tutorial) measured how fast it is with and without parallelism. The results were surprising:

```
$ ./sudoku3 sudoku17.1000.txt +RTS -s -N1
   1,181,490,684 bytes allocated in the heap
      13,247,408 bytes copied during GC
       1,094,432 bytes maximum residency (5 sample(s))
          35,556 bytes maximum slop
               3 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      2282 colls,     0 par    0.07s    0.08s     0.0000s    0.0061s
  Gen  1         5 colls,     0 par    0.01s    0.01s     0.0012s    0.0044s

  TASKS: 3 (1 bound, 2 peak workers (2 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 1000 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 1000 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    2.51s  (  2.90s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.08s  (  0.08s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    2.59s  (  2.98s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    469,886,714 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  97.0% of total user, 84.3% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 0
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0
```

Here the run with two cores:

```
$ ./sudoku3 sudoku17.1000.txt +RTS -s -N2
   1,207,033,704 bytes allocated in the heap
      23,422,808 bytes copied during GC
       1,066,716 bytes maximum residency (22 sample(s))
          47,524 bytes maximum slop
               5 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1488 colls,  1488 par    0.40s    0.40s     0.0003s    0.0147s
  Gen  1        22 colls,    21 par    0.07s    0.06s     0.0026s    0.0087s

  Parallel GC work balance: 39.57% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N2)

  SPARKS: 1000 (968 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 32 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    3.45s  (  2.96s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.47s  (  0.45s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    3.93s  (  3.41s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    349,389,354 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  88.0% of total user, 101.4% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 913
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 25
gen[1].sync: 0
```

Surprisingly the run with two cores was slower. Why is this?

My GHC version is 7.6.3
Operating System: Debian Jessie Linux/GNU i386 (i686)

Comment: Parallelization (distributing tasks, collecting results) comes with some overhead, perhaps you need a problem instance that needs more computing to reap benefits?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `-N2` is nearly twice as fast on my machine.

Comment: @mvw That's what I thought at first, but since the example I'm using is an example specifically created to show the benefit of parallelization I would be surprised if it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you're comparing wall clock time and not CPU time?  I had mistakenly looked at CPU time when trying to reproduce.  Using *nix `time` command should give a slightly clearer English result.  EDIT: It appears `-s` gives wall clock time too and you're output does indeed show `-N2` is slower, odd.  Can not reproduce with ghc 7.8.x on Linux x86_64.

Comment: You can measure Haskell programs using the -s RTS option (`./foo +RTS -s`). It does measure both wall clock time and CPU time. Since I pasted the raw results you can look them up both. (I guess the elapsed value is the wall clock time.)

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/ThreadScope_Tour/Spark seems to give hints on measuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did the test again and like expected the parallel version is faster.

It turns out, it is a bad idea to measure performance, while the CPU is 100% busy converting videos.

Comment: -_- Well ya. That'll do it.

Comment: It's a good idea to run tasks like video conversion with the lowest CPU+disk priority. I usually call `ionice -c3 schedtool -D -n15 -e command args`.